# Windows Server 2008 Thin Client-Google Chrome issue

Tags: windows-server-2008, google-chrome

I work in a school system, and there is a thin client lab where 30 clients connect to a win2008 standard server, all using the same username. All clients were able to successfully launch chrome. After another admin reinstalled chrome using the new msi installer, only one client can launch chrome. Is there a workaround to get chrome running again on all clients?
Thanks!

Comment: What happens when a non-working client launches Chrome?

Comment: nothing happens at all

Answer (score 2):

If you are running this on a server with the Remote Desktop Services role (which it sounds like) you need to install the program one of two ways. You can either:

Run `change user /install` from the command prompt, then install the program, then run `change user /execute`

**or**

You can install the programs from the "Programs" applet in Control Panel. This will automatically change the modes as required.

[This link](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Installing_Applications_for_Windows_Server_2008_R2_Remote_Desktop_Services) has some details with screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably the problem is that all clients try to access the same profile in the same time. Chrome used to ignore this before but it was a time bomb as there is no synchronization between the clients and they might and will corrupt the profile. Now Chrome can detect this situation and will not start a second instance of the browser on the same profile.

Try running every client with a different profile directory by using the --user-data-dir command line or the UserDataDir group policy and this should solve your issue.